# List not filling maximum space in Stack panel

Tags: wpf, listbox, panel, stackpanel

I have the following code, I think the List should fill out the entire space occupied by the stack panel, I tried using Grid but it didn't work.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ListBox x:Name="substanceList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource symTable}}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Count,  Converter={StaticResource stringToIntConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"/>
                        <Separator/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button x:Name="graphButtonStackPanel" Content="Graph" Click="graphButtonStackPanel_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: You could have posted the non-working Grid code which would still be better than a StackPanel which will never do what you want....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StackPanels` stack things, if you want your content stretched use a `Grid`. e.g.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition /> <!-- Takes remaining space -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> <!-- Resizes to content -->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: I had what you posted, but it doesn't expand the list.

Comment: I guess a solution is to put them in column, but then it stacks them on top of each, which kind of works, but you can't see the content in the list under the button.

Comment: @mihajlv: You need to set [the attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.column.aspx) on the controls to place them in their respective columns, otherwise everything is on top of each other.

Comment: @mihajlv: Did you ever look at the documentation of the [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) class before using it?

Comment: I had it reversed, I was putting the List in column=0 and was setting it the width to Auto, thinking that Auto would fill the whole space. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Stack panels grow to fit their content, not the other way round.

It could just be that there isn't enough content to fill your available space.